# return a function if there was no click event

Tags: javascript

I have a function that fires only when we press the spacebar or the isJumping event is already happening

If we press any other key, nothing happens.

```
function onJump(e) {
  if (e.code !== "Space" || isJumping) return

  yVelocity = JUMP_SPEED
  isJumping = true
}
```

The question is, can I add to this function so that, in addition to the space, the mouse click event also fires?

That is, if we press the spacebar or click on the mouse, then the function works

The mouse click event is not key code, so I'm a little confused on how to do it right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call function with mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477529/call-function-with-mouse-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE EVENT.TYPE**

Use the `event.type` property when using a single handler for multiple events.  In your case, you want the same function to handle keyboard and mouse events. View and run the code snippet below to see how it works.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", onJump);

window.addEventListener("mousedown", onJump);

const JUMP_SPEED = 100;
let isJumping = false;

function onJump(e) {
  
  if (e.type === "mousedown") {
    
    // add event handler here
    
  }
  else if (e.type === "keydown" && e.code === "Space" && !isJumping) {
    yVelocity = JUMP_SPEED
    isJumping = true
  }
  
  console.log("event: " + e.type + ", isJumping: " + isJumping + ", keycode: " + e.code);
 
}
```

```html
<h3>Click the mouse or press spacebar</h3>

<img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/567/PNG/512/packman_icon-icons.com_54382.png" style="height:100px;width:auto"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function is called when you press a key then that is because *somewhere in the code you didn't show us* you have some code which registers that function (or another function which calls the first) as an event handler that triggers when a key is pressed (e.g. `keyup` or `keypress`).

If you want to call it when something is clicked then you also need to register it as an event handler for that kind of event (e.g. `click` or `mousedown`).

---

MDN has a [tutorial on event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Answer (score 1):

I assume `onJump` is attached to a keyboard event handler, presumably on `document`, something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", onJump);
```

If so, you can also attach it to `click`:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", onJump);
document.addEventListener("click", onJump);
```

...and then modify the function so it checks which [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type) of event it got and handles it accordingly:

```
function onJump(e) {
    if (isJumping || (e.type === "keydown" && e.code !== "Space")) return;
  
    yVelocity = JUMP_SPEED;
    isJumping = true;
}
```

That will only check `e.code` if the event is the `keydown` event, not the `click` event. (Adjust the event name as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a event listener, like this:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('hi');
});
```

```html
<body>
<p>This is supposed to be your elements. Click here!</p>
</body>
```

In your case, you can make it

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", onJump);
document.addEventListener("click", onJump);
```

You can change your function correspondingly, so that it works with the event listeners:

```js
function onJump(e) {
if (isJumping || (e.type == "keydown" && e.code !== "space")) return;
   yVelocity = JUMP_SPEED;
   isJumping = true;
}
```